# Java JsonObject from JsonArray

Tags: java, json, format

I have Json stored in javax.json.JsonObject, the object look like this:

```
{  
 "status":"ok",
 "meta":{  
    "count":2
 },
 "data":{  
    "1":{  
       "id":40,
    },
    "17":{  
       "id":48,
    }
 }
```

}

How do I access the id key in the sub-object "1" ?

I tried:

```
obj.getJsonArray("data").getJsonArray("1").getJsonNumber("id").intValue();
```

However it does not work because the firt call of getJsonArray() method returns a JsonValue object not a JsonObject so the next call of getJsonArray fails. Any ideas ?

Comment: Why are you using `getJsonArray` if all your stuff is not in arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iterator approach to iterate thru the JSONObject:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(input);

JSONObject jsonData = json.getJSONObject("data");
Iterator<?> jsonDataKeys = jsonData.keys();

while (jsonDataKeys.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String)jsonDataKeys.next();
    if (jsonData.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
        System.out.println(((JSONObject) jsonData.get(key)).getInt("id"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int id = obj.getJsonObject("data")
                .getJsonObject("1")
                .getInt("id");
```

Comment: There should be at least one sentence explaining what question this code is addressing.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jObject = null;    
jObject = new JSONObject(String you want to parse);
JSONObject j1Object = jObject.getJSONObject("data");
JSONObject j2Object = j1Object.getJSONObject("1");
String s1=j2Object.getString("id");
System.out.println(s1);
```